# why i always doing make commad after installation success

Tags: unix, makefile, command

I successfuly installed LEDAPS source with make command, but when my console/terminal close or putty exit, I doing make command again to install it on my OS. Do you know why ? I want install it permanent.

Here installation steps:

```
source env.sh

make

make install

make clean
```

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking, but I think you need to `sudo make install` to install it into `/usr/local/`.

Comment: I mean this , first I install Leadaps source (software for image processing ) using terminal, Its success i can run the software with no problem. But when I close terminal or shutdown computer then I turn on computer or open terminal, the software Not run. So I must repeat installation again with that "make command". My problem is how to install it once and permanently , so when I wanna use it sometimes , I dont need to install. Thanks you so much sir